# Usage of auxiliary verb with question

Tags: word-order, interrogatives, subject-auxiliary-inversion

I am really confused with the word order of English.

> How can you go to your sister's house this afternoon?

> How you can go to your sister's house this afternoon?

In the first sentence we put the auxiliary verb *before* the verb, while in the second sentence we use an auxiliary verb *after* verb.

On which occasion does one use the above two sentences.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! This question may be better suited to our sister site, [ell.se]. That notwithstanding, second sentence is completely wrong, always use the first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing subject and verb positions in statements and questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1553/changing-subject-and-verb-positions-in-statements-and-questions)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know where you got your second sentence -- let's call them (1) and (2), OK?
As pointed out, (2) is ungrammatical as a question, so let's mark it with an asterisk "*".

1. *How can you go to your sister's house this afternoon?*
2. **How you can go to your sister's house this afternoon?*

That is, sentence (2) is wrong in standard English; you shouldn't use it. That answers your question.

More than that, however, it means that if anyone taught you to ask a question that way, they were wrong as far as standard English is concerned; and that anybody around you that would ask an English question like (2) is doing it wrong for standard English.

This kind of question may well be common, however, in the English spoken by people around you, especially if they are not native English speakers, or if there is a distinctive local English dialect, like Indian English.

The reason for the confusion, I think, is that (3) (which is (2) without the question mark or capital),

3. *how you can go to your sister's house this afternoon*

**does** occur grammatically in standard English. But **not** as a question, only as a complement clause;

- *I don't know **how you can go to your sister's house this afternoon**; we're not done.*

in this case *how you can go to your sister's house this afternoon* is an embedded question complement clause that's the direct object of *I don't know*.

The big difference between a real question that should take a question mark and should start with a capital letter is that real questions **invert** the subject and the auxiliary verb (and if there isn't an auxiliary verb, invert *do*) like (1), while embedded question subordinate clauses **don't** invert them (and therefore don't use *do*) like (3). (2) is ungrammatical only because it's used as a question.

Comment: BTW, although I didn't say so explicitly in this answer before it was transferred here, _can_ **is** an auxiliary verb in English, as are _be, have, do,_ and the other 8 modals and 2 semimodals; they all invert with the subject in questions if they're the first verb (in a negative context for semimodals).